# Does a road that "snakes" always imply a "winding" road?

Tags: meaning, figures-of-speech

If one says that a road *snakes*, does it necessarily imply that the road is *winding*?  Or can it also express that the road is *long* and *stretched out*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb *snakes* indicates that something winds or twists.

New Oxford American Dictionary:

> **snake** v. [*intrans.*] move or extend with the twisting motion of a snake

[Wiktionary definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snake#Verb):

> To move in a winding path.